# Forall'd constraint is not bound in RULE by lhs

Tags: haskell, ghc, pragma

I'm messing around with the `SPECIALIZE` pragma while trying to find a solution to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803949/style-vs-performance-using-vectors).

I came up with this example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Data.Vector
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as V

class Foo a

newtype Phantom m = T Int deriving (Show)

instance (Foo m) => Num (Phantom m)

f :: (Num r, V.Vector v r) => v r -> v r -> v r
{-# SPECIALIZE f :: (Foo m) => Vector (Phantom m) -> Vector (Phantom m) -> Vector (Phantom m) #-}
f x y = V.zipWith (+) x y

main = print "hello"
```

which fails to compile (GHC 7.6.2) because

`` Forall'd constraint `Foo m' is not bound in RULE lhs ``.

Googling only turned up a couple of GHC bug reports from years ago. I didn't see anything about "forall'd constraints" while reading about [`SPECIALIZE`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#specialize-pragma) or [`RULE`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html). My specialize signature does seem less polymorphic than the original, and it satisfies the ["if-and-only-if" rule](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#specialize-pragma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace with

```
{-# SPECIALIZE f :: (Num (Phantom m)) => Vector (Phantom m) -> Vector (Phantom m) -> Vector (Phantom m) #-}
```

and it will work.  The `r` in `Num r` is `Phantom m` not `m`, thus you can't add the constraint `Num m`.  This is logical--`Num (Phantom m)` does not imply `Num m` and you could get other instances under the open world assumption.

EDIT:
You actually don't need any constraint at all in this case

```
{-# SPECIALIZE f :: Vector (Phantom m) -> Vector (Phantom m) -> Vector (Phantom m) #-}
```

anyway, the basic problem if I understand what you are trying to do is that you can't constrain when you perform an optimization based on phantom type parameters.

Comment: I'm automatically deriving `Num` for `Phantom m`, and the derived instance shouldn't need any constraints, as the newtype is a synonym for Int. I was really trying to restrict the little-p phantom type. Perhaps `Num` was a poor choice for my constraint on `m`. Make it `Foo m` for any type `Foo :: * -> *`

Comment: Clearly I simplified the problem too much. I updated the problem again so that the `Foo m` constraint is needed as part of `Phantom m`'s `Num` instance. So what I'd *like* to constrain is the phantom type itself. I see that I can accomplish minimal specialization using the `Num (Phantom m)` constraint as you suggested, but is there a way to specialize further for more specific classes of m? Maybe `Bar` inherits from `Foo`, and I'd like to specialize for `Bar m`. At any rate, I'm really interested in what this error means.