# Why does introducing associated types kill my performance?

Tags: haskell, type-families, associated-types

In my [`kdtree`](https://github.com/fhaust/kdtree) project I just replaced a depth counter from being `Int`-based to an explicit `Key a` based on the type `a` in `KDTree v a`. This is the [diff](https://github.com/fhaust/kdtree/commit/5cec941da5c4a88caf044702fd38ed6b0837b265).

Now while I believe this should be a type-level change only my benchmarks show a sharp drop in performance:

Before:

```
benchmarking nr/kdtree_nr 
mean: 60.19084 us, lb 59.87414 us, ub 60.57270 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 1.777527 us, lb 1.494657 us, ub 2.120168 us, ci 0.950
```

After:

```
benchmarking nr/kdtree_nr 
mean: 556.9518 us, lb 554.0586 us, ub 560.6128 us, ci 0.950 
std dev: 16.70620 us, lb 13.58185 us, ub 20.63450 us, ci 0.950
```

Before I dive into *Core* ... anyone has any idea what's going on here?

### Edit 1

As proposed by Thomas (and userxyz) I replaced `data Key a :: *` with `type Key a :: *` and changed the implementation accordingly. This hasn't had any significent impact on the result:

```
benchmarking nr/kdtree_nr
mean: 538.2789 us, lb 537.5128 us, ub 539.4408 us, ci 0.950
std dev: 4.745118 us, lb 3.454081 us, ub 6.969091 us, ci 0.950
```

### Edit 2

Just had a quick look at the Core output. Apparently the change prevents functions depending on the class to be specialized, right?

Before:

```
lvl20 :: KDTree Vector (V3 Double) -> [V3 Double]
lvl20 =
  \ (w4 :: KDTree Vector (V3 Double)) ->
    $wpointsAround $fKDCompareV3_$s$fKDCompareV3 lvl2 lvl4 nrRadius q w4
```

After:

```
lvl18 :: KDTree Vector (V3 Double) -> [V3 Double]
lvl18 =
  \ (w4 :: KDTree Vector (V3 Double)) ->
    $wpointsAround $dKDCompare lvl1 lvl3 nrRadius q w4
```

Small Update to *Edit 2*: Going crazy with *INLINE pragmas* doesn't change a thing here.

### Edit 3

Quickly implemented what *userxyz* suggested: http://lpaste.net/104457
Been there before, can't make it to work:

```
src/Data/KDTree.hs:48:49:
    Could not deduce (k ~ KeyV3)
    from the context (Real a, Floating a)
      bound by the instance declaration at src/Data/KDTree.hs:45:10-49
    or from (Key k)
      bound by the type signature for
                 dimDistance :: Key k => k -> V3 a -> V3 a -> Double
      at src/Data/KDTree.hs:47:3-13
      ‘k’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            dimDistance :: Key k => k -> V3 a -> V3 a -> Double
          at src/Data/KDTree.hs:47:3
    Relevant bindings include
      k :: k (bound at src/Data/KDTree.hs:47:15)
      dimDistance :: k -> V3 a -> V3 a -> Double
        (bound at src/Data/KDTree.hs:47:3)
    In the pattern: V3X
    In a case alternative: V3X -> ax - bx
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘case k of {
         V3X -> ax - bx
         V3Y -> ay - by
         V3Z -> az - bz }’
```

### Edit 4

Hmm ... I think I just "solved" the problem by just throwing *SPECIALIZE* pragmas at the functions. This in effect causes everything to be inlined and removes the explicit dictionary passing.

I am not too happy with that solution as this means I have to put a big "please specialize your calls to achieve decent performance" warning in the docs.

Comment: There are, or used to be, many re-write rules that are specialized to `Int`.  This was made painfully apparent when changing functions from `Int` to `Word32`, `Int64`, etc.  Instead of a newtype could you use a type alias and see how things go?

Comment: You mean changing [line 26](https://github.com/fhaust/kdtree/blob/associated_types/src/Data/KDTree.hs#L26) to `type Key a :: *`? I tried that, but then the typechecker isn't able to deduce the type in several other functions. Additionally I hope to change the `Int` to some kind of enum so that I can address the dimensions directly.

Comment: What specifically goes wrong if you change the `data Key a :: *` to a `type Key a :: *`?

Comment: @Florian Yes, you understood my suggestion correctly.  I understand an alias removes information and is not always possible or desireable.  In this case if a hack-job is possible then the results might strongly suggest (or not) the existence of optimizations that could be made more general.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson tried that, see edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By sheer chance I just stumbled upon this question: [Transitivity of Auto-Specialization in GHC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502335/transitivity-of-auto-specialization-in-ghc)

There the OP quotes "From [the docs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#idp49866112) for GHC 7.6:" (emphasis mine):

> [Y]ou often don't even need the **SPECIALIZE** pragma in the first place. When compiling a module M, GHC's optimiser (with -O) automatically considers each top-level overloaded function declared in M, and specialises it for the different types at which it is called in M. The optimiser also considers each imported **INLINABLE** overloaded function, and specialises it for the different types at which it is called in M.

As a result I have just removed all (hard) **INLINE** and **SPECIALIZE** pragmas and replaced them with **INLINEABLE** pragmas where appropriate (ie on each function that is used in the benchmark suite). As a result I get even better times than with inline pragmas on all functions.

Quintessence: let the compiler do it's work but give him a hint sometimes.

Comment: The fact that I have just answered my own second question this week probably is a sign that I should investigate more before I ask questions here ...

Comment: I was going to send you that direction, glad you found it!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be helpful because it doesn't address the real question, which is the code slows down, but you can make this work with `type` instead of `data`. The reason `kFirst` and `kSucc` don't work is because there is no way to deduce what `a` is from their application, so there is no way to select an instance, since the instance depends only on `a` and not `Key a`. You can fix this by providing a witness for those functions:

```
class KDCompare a where
  type Key a :: *

  kSuccWith :: proxy a -> Key a -> Key a
  kFirstWith :: proxy a -> Key a
```

Then modifying your functions accordingly:

```
kdtree :: (KDCompare a, G.Vector v a) => BucketSize -> v a -> KDTree v a
kdtree mb vs = ana (kdtreeF mb) (kFirstWith vs, vs) 

kdtreeF :: (KDCompare a, G.Vector v a) => BucketSize -> (Key a,v a) -> KDTreeF v a (Key a,v a)
kdtreeF (BucketSize mb) (k0, v0) = go (k0, v0)
  where go (k,fs) | G.length fs <= mb = LeafF (G.convert fs)
                  | otherwise         = NodeF k (G.head r) (kSucc' k,l) (kSucc' k,r)
                    where (l,r) = splitBuckets k fs
                          kSucc' = kSuccWith v0
```

It would probably make more sense to just seperate `Key` and `KDCompare`:

```
class Enum a => Key a where 
  kSucc :: a -> a
  kFirst :: a

class KDCompare a where
  dimDistance  :: Key key => key -> a -> a -> Double
  realDistance :: a -> a -> Double
```

Then your datatype has to be parameterised over the key:

```
data KDTree k v a = Node k a (KDTree k v a) (KDTree k v a)
                    | Leaf (v a)


data KDTreeF k v a f = NodeF k a f f | LeafF (v a)
  deriving (Functor)
```

But your functions can be written more naturally:

```
kdtree :: (Key key, KDCompare a, G.Vector v a) => BucketSize -> v a -> KDTree key v a
kdtree mb vs = ana (kdtreeF mb) (kFirst, vs)
```

Comment: Tried the first part, see edit above. For the second part I am not sure that I want that. `Key a` is inherently bound to `a`, eg `Key V3` should be `V3X | V3Y | V3Z`. Additionally, I tried something along this lines before getting to *associated types* / *type families* and couldn't make it work.