# Would you ever write seq x x?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I'm not entirely clear on how seq works in Haskell.

It seems like it there are lots of cases where it would be useful to write

```
seq x x
```

and maybe even define a function:

```
strict x = seq x x
```

but such a function doesn't already exist so I'm guessing this approach is somehow wrongheaded.  Could someone tell me if this is meaningful or useful?

Comment: Have you read [the wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Seq) on it?  It does a good job of explaining the nuances of `seq`, since it isn't completely straightforward.

Comment: “In particular, the expression ``x `seq` x`` is completely redundant, and always has exactly the same effect as just writing `x`”

Comment: Related: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19805521/925978), and more importantly, the comments below it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`seq a b` returns the value of `b`, but makes that value depend on the evaluation of `a`. Thus, `seq a a` is exactly the same thing as `a`.

I think the misunderstanding here is that `seq` doesn't take any action, because pure functions don't take actions, it just introduces a dependency.

There is a function `evaluate :: a -> IO ()` in `Control.Exception` that does what you want (note that it's in `IO`). They put it in exception because it's useful to see if the evaluation of an expression would throw, and if so handle the exception.

Answer (score 8):

The expression `x = seq a b` means that *if* `x` is evaluated, then `a` will also be evaluated (but `x` will be equal to `b`).

It does *not* mean "evaluate `a` now".

Notice that if `x` is being evaluated, then since `x` equals `b`, then `b` will also be evaluated.

And hence, if I write `x = seq a a`, I am saying "if `x` is evaluated then evaluate `a`". But if I just do `x = a`, that would achieve *exactly the same thing*.

Comment: I believe you meant `a` will also be evaluated, in the 1st sentence.

Answer (score 6):

When you say `seq a b` what you are telling the computer is,

> Whenever you need to evaluate `b`, evaluate `a` for me too, please.

If we replace both `a` and `b` with `x` you can see why it's useless to write `seq x x`:

> Whenever you need to evaluate `x`, evaluate `x` for me too, please.

Asking the computer to evaluate `x` when it needs to evaluate `x` is just a useless thing to do – it was going to evaluate `x` anyway!

`seq` does *not* evaluate anything – it simply tells the computer that *when* you need the second argument, also evaluate the first argument. Understanding this is actually really important, because it allows you to understand the behaviour of your programs much better.

Answer (score 5):

`seq x x` would be entirely, trivially redundant.

Remember, `seq` is *not a command*. The presence of a `seq a b` in your program does not force evaluation of `a` or `b` What it does do, is it makes the evaluation of the result artificially dependent on the evaluation of `a`, even though the result itself is `b` If you print out `seq a b`, `a` will be evaluated and its result discarded.. Since `x` already depends on itself, `seq x x` is silly.

Answer (score 1):

Close! [`deepseq`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v%3adeepseq) (which is the "more thorough" `seq` -- see the docs for a full description) has the type `NFData a => a -> b -> b`, and [`force`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v%3aforce) (with type `NFData a => a -> a`) is defined simply as

```
force :: (NFData a) => a -> a
force x = x `deepseq` x
```